# Where are questions about software packaging mechanics on topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic

Today I had two (ancient) questions of mine closed as 'off topic'.  Both relate to Debian packaging mechanics.

- [Is it possible to specify a range of versions for a conflict in a Debian package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11995748/13860)
- [How can I force a udeb to build with gzip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12396957/13860)

I don't really care so much that these question were closed; after this much time, they're not likely to get answers.

I've moved on from those problems with other work-arounds.  So I'm really only asking for the sake of future possible questions.

I was clearly under the impression that questions on the mechanics of building packages were on-topic, as they relate to programming, although admittedly a somewhat narrow aspect of programming.

If they are off-topic on SO, are they on-topic somewhere else?

Comment: This question is strange by today's standards, A) it asks for a site recommendation (and that's ok here). B) it gives two examples of Qs being closed on SO (and that's also common with site-recommendation Qs). The problem is the 2nd to last paragraph debates on-topicness on SO (that's kinda off-topic here) and goes on to ask a recommendation that's entirely based off it not being on-topic at SO. So the problem is reading the question itself is messy, and the answer doesn't address nor solve the problem by today's standards either. The best choice likely is closure.

Comment: @bad_coder The original did not ask for a site recommendation. The original question was asked about SO, before meta.SE split off of meta.SO.  So really, this question should have been migrated to meta.SO many years ago, before the edit.

Comment: FYI, I've been going through some old questions e.g. [`[stack-overflow] is:q closed:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[stack-overflow]+is:q+closed:no) and there's literally thousands needing closure for several reasons Don't take it the wrong way, I wrote the comment as an explanation for reviewers, you the OP, and future readers.

Comment: @bad_coder: Thanks for doing that. I didn't take it the wrong way. Was also just adding an explanation. I don't mind that this was closed. It served it's purpose... nearly a dacade ago :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/on-topic) does list:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

with the intent being software tools which are used by programmers, for programming-related tasks.

I think both of these questions are on-topic, since they're both programming-related questions about programming-relevant software. I would vote to reopen them if I hadn't been too lazy the past few weeks to push above 3k.